# What is the generic type of this background image?

Tags: website-design, background-image

What is [this type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXolo.jpg) of texture referred to in web design? Blotted, blotched? And what are the best ways or tools to generate similar textures and backgrounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that's been generated at all.
You can poke around the search results for something along the line of "speckled paper Photoshop tutorial," find one you like and then learn how to do it, but it'll probably be faster to just go to your nearest art store, buy some actual paper in whatever color you want, and run it through a scanner. Or have a poke around some [stock photography sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=speckled+paper+stock&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=fe5DT8-bI8XbggfWq4mGCA&biw=1032&bih=863&sei=gO5DT93cJI3AgAeD8dmDCA).

Comment: Stock image sites will probably have a good selection, but if you do decide to make an image yourself, you should use a scanner instead of a camera, since it'll be hard to pick up the fine textures using regular cameras without a macro lense. As well, unless you have a way to mount the paper and camera, it'll be very hard to get a perfectly face-on shot.

Comment: Erm, yes. Scanner. I don't know what I was thinking when I typed that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a decent primer on [background textures in web design from smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/07/textures-in-modern-web-design/) and a further article from the same site [on how to find more](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/01/02/where-can-i-find-textures-and-background-images/) (there are tons of high quality free ones about the web).

The texture you've posted looks like paper to me, and it's style is 'tiled' in the sense that it needs to be repeated up and down the page to work.